# OpenCV: Which technique toproject the points in the resized image back to the original image size?

Tags: opencv, resize

I used OpenCV's "GoodFeatureToTrack" to find features and track them down on the second image.

To speed up the process, I down-sample the image 4 times smaller, let say from 4000x2000 to 1000x500, using bilinear interpolation.

The KLT match the points perfectly on the resized image. BUT I want to have the point positions in the original image size.

I tried multiplying the feature positions I got on the resized image by 4 (to the original-sized image). It seems to me that after multiplying, the corresponding features on the resized image are not longer corresponding in the original image size.

Do I need interpolation (?) or else to project the points in the resized image back to the original image size? so that corresponding features in the resized image still match in the original image size.

Thank you very much.

Please excuse me that my English is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downsizing will result in a loss of precision. However, oftentimes this loss is so small that it cannot be detected. If your points are far from their correct position, it may be that the multiplication step is wrong.

The formula you wrote there is correct, namely

```
pointInBigImage = scale*pointInSmallImage
```

where scale is 4, in your case.

You should print the points in both images, and display them side by side. Then, compare visually the positions in the two images. This way, you'll see whether it's a bug or a loss of precision.

And finally, to improve precision you can use cornerSubpix - this is a function in OpenCV that extract a corner's position with subpixel precision - so when you'll multiply them back to the original image, the accuracy should be better

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. At least I know that others do the same. The corresponding points are slightly different (a few pixels). I just wonder if there are any way to reduce this small discrepancy. I already used the corner subpixel.

Comment: It may be that you have to live with it - but the question is whether you need that precision - if you really need it, you can re-calculate their position in the bigger image. Bt oftentimes, it is not the case. You may be able to average some of those points and have a good final accuracy - that depends on the next steps of the algorithm

Comment: Thank you for giving me more comments. Can you please tell me what do you mean for "you can re-calculate their position in the bigger image."? I'm thinking that it might be a result of image distortion. I will have to check this also.

Comment: The whole idea to work on a small image is to gain speed, but once you know the interest points, you can go back to the big image, and around the corners found in the first step, perform a new search for corners, to find the actual, accurate position. It should still be faster than processing the whole big image, but it depends.

Comment: Welcome. Don't forget that on stackoverflow, the way to say thank you is to upvote/accept the answer